# What is the right way to organize class contents?

Tags: php, oop, object

While I was designing a bunch of classes, I found myself wondering if there is a standard for where to place these relative to each other:

```
private $property
public $property
public static $property
function __construct
public function __get
public static function
public function
private function
protected function
```

etc

Comment: The convention, as I know it, is public first, the protected, then private. The idea being that the most accessible to other developers be given up front.

Comment: How about static functions relative to other functions relative to the constructor?

Comment: I'd wait till others weigh in if I were you, but I'd say group static with their access group and just keep them together in a block. Constructors/Copy Const should probably be first at the top of public. I'd put the destructors with private as they aren't needed for the general public usage.

Comment: I go constructor, then methods in visibility order (public, protected, private), then destructor, then properties in visibility order, then static methods in visibility order, then static properties in visibility order.

Comment: You can check [PSR-2](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/), which is the only thing I'm aware of that's an "official"-like standard (I suppose there's the PEAR contributor standards and ones I don't know about). However, there's got to be multiple ways to approach it otherwise. This type of question isn't really a good fit for SO's Q&A format.

Comment: ^^ As @JaredFarrish alluded to, PSR-2 is the closest thing PHP's community has ever had to agreeing on coding standards (and I personally disagree with large swaths of it :-D) but it doesn't specifically address this.